# Hibernate search java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException exception

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web service running inside Tomcat 6 on an Amazon EC2 (Amazon Linux) instance. It uses Hibernate Search. I have added very basic hibernate search configuration. I keep getting java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException: null exception for this.

```
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1088)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1154)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:217)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:72)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1098)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

below are the causes :-
1. there are two applications, with same index location. 
2. application server clustering.
3. entry like  under Host (application serever)

please verify.